Log in to Azure SQL database using created managed identity
I want to create an Azure SQL Server/Database that can only be accessed by a web app that is running in Azure.
After creating the web app, I ran the following command:
az webapp identity assign --name MY_NAME --resource_group MY_GROUP
Let's say the prinicpalId is XXX.
Then I created the server and database using these two commands:
az sql server create --enable-ad-only-auth --external-admin-principal-type Application --external-admin-name SOME_NAME --external-admin-sid XXX --resource-group MY_GROUP --name MY_SERVER
az sql db create --name MY_DATABASE --resource-group MY_GROUP --server MY_SERVER --tier GeneralPurpose --compute-model Serverless --family Gen5 --min-capacity 0.5 --capacity 1 --auto-pause-delay 60 --backup-storage-redundancy Local --zone-redundant false
The problem is that I now have to run the queries below in order to allow the web app access to the server and database, but I can't use the query editor or Azure Data Studio because I have configured the server such that only the web app is ever allowed to access the server.
What can I do in order to run these queries? Do I temporarily give myself access, run the queries, and then remove the access again?
CREATE USER some_user_name FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER some_user_name;
ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER some_user_name;
ALTER ROLE db_ddladmin   ADD MEMBER some_user_name;

Ideally, you create a Azure AD (Entra) group, then add whoever needs to connect to Database to this role.

So would I then add both (myself) and (the webapp identity assign) to this group?

it depends. If you are using IAC to create those resources using GH Actions for example, you should have a service principal which permissions to create those resources. Then, this one (SP) will be a member of that group and you will never have to connect to the DB. If that is not the case, then you will need to be a member of that group. Tha Managed identity won't need as you are creating a login for it

I will have to connect to the DB myself, so I have added myself to the group. When running a local Python application I still can't login with the connection string that Azure "gave me" - which contains Authentication=ActiveDirectoryIntegrated - so I guess I'll have to figure out why.

Could you please provide the error which is you are getting while connecting to sql database through python application with Authentication=ActiveDirectoryIntegrated?

Sure, the error is: pyodbc.OperationalError: ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')


I will have to connect to the DB myself, so I have added myself to the group. When running a local Python application I still can't login with the connection string that Azure "gave me" - which contains Authentication=ActiveDirectoryIntegrated - so I guess I'll have to figure out why.

If you want to authenticate with ActiveDirectory to an Azure SQL database from a Python application, make sure your Entra Id is assigned to the SQL database as shown below:

Otherwise, add it using the Set admin option. If you want to connect an Azure SQL database with Active Directory Integrated authentication,

you must federate the on-premises Active Directory Federation Services (ADFS) with Microsoft Entra ID in the cloud.

I suggest you try using Active Directory Interactive Authentication instead of Active Directory Integrated Authentication. You can use the code below:
import urllib.parse
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

server = '<serverName>.database.windows.net'
database = '<datbaseName>'
user = '<EntarId>'

driver = 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'
conn = f'DRIVER={driver};SERVER={server};DATABASE={database};UID={user};Authentication=ActiveDirectoryInteractive'
conn_str = urllib.parse.quote_plus(conn)

engine = create_engine(f'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={conn_str}', fast_executemany=True)

with engine.connect() as connection:
    result = connection.execute("SELECT 1")
    print(result.scalar())

It will connect to the Azure SQL database successfully with Entra Id authentication as shown below:

If you want to connect with Managed Identity authentication to your Python application, you can refer to this.

I added the admin and in the connection string I used ActiveDirectoryInteractive, which did not work, but I think I know why. I created a security group in Microsoft Entra, to which I added myself and the web app's system-assigned identity. And it is this group that I set as the admin. Do I need to include the group's UID in the connection string? Or is there another reason why me trying to connect from my local Python script does not work? (I am logged in using az login by the way.)

Use the UID which you used for az login.
